# Adding Infopath forms into different libraries

Tags: deployment, 2010

I am following this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231524.aspx) to add some infopath forms into different doc lib when a site is provisioned.

`<File Path="Module1\File-01.xml" Url="./SalesLib1/File-01.xml" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />` this gives me an error "the file or folder name sitecoll/subsite/futuresite/. contains invalid characters.

`<File Path="Module1\File-01.xml" Url="SalesLib1/File-01.xml" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />` this give me error no url found

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what else your doing as part of the site definition I'd consider doing this using a web scoped feature and use feature stapling rather than creating a new site definition.
It would also be helpful if you could post the Modules element as well from the definition.

Anyway here's an xml snippet of provisioning files from a definition:

```
<Module Name="SampleForms" Path="Files\SampleForms" Url="SampleFormsLibrary">
    <File Url="SampleForm1.xml" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <Property Name="Title" Value="Sample Form 1" />         
        <Property Name="ContentType" Value="SampleForm" />
    </File>
    <File Url="SampleForm2.xml" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
        <Property Name="Title" Value="Sample Form 2" />         
        <Property Name="ContentType" Value="SampleForm" />
    </File>
</Module>
```

So in the above example the directory structure of the definition would be:

```
MyDefintion
  Files
    SampleForms
      SampleForm1.xml
      SampleForm2.xml
  XML
    onet.xml
...
```

Make sure the Lists element that creates the destination library is above the Modules element within the Configuration section of your onet.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered publishing the form as a farm solution? Then it can be activated at the appropriate level and used within the document library.

Comment: It's a farm solution. I heard this is a good way to implement. Lists are supposed to be created before module since creation of the list is in onet.xml. I also tried url="/libraryname/filename" but i got the "the url /libraryname is invalid

Comment: So you are trying to implement the sites using a custom site definition?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.